# array of objects with multiple parameters using a pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers

How do I switch both parameters of the class to the object that I am creating with a pointer? What is the syntax? (They must receive all the same parameters)

In a normal situation I use this:

```
MyClass obj[5]={MyClass(x,y)}
```

But... in this case what is the syntax? :

```
MyClass *obj;
obj = new MyClass[5]; //Here! <----
```

How can I pass the two parameters?

Comment: Why do you think you need to create the array using `new`?

Comment: @NeilButterworth This is because within the code I need to generate *obj in a file and assign the object subsequently. There are other ways to do this?

Comment: Your "normal situation" isn't doing what you think it's doing. Only the *first* array element will be `MyClass(x, y)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no syntax to list-initialize a dynamically allocated array.

You must

- Either 1) default construct as in the example you show, and modify the objects after creation.
- Or 2) allocate an array of char of sufficient size, and construct the objects with placement-new.

1) is not an option if the class is not default constructible. 2) is a bit complicated, but you don't have to do that yourself since `std::vector` has already implemented it for you. You should be using vector anyway since it takes care of memory management.

An example with vector, that is analogous to your "normal situation". Note that your "normal situation" doesn't match the description in your question:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v{
    {x1, y1},
    {x2, y2},
    ...
};
```

An example with vector, that matches your description of passing same argument to all objects in the array. Although technically, this copy-constructs the array elements:

```
std::vector<MyClass> v(5, {x, y});
```

Comment: When i use v(5, {x, y}) in a initializer list, i get this 
warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
It could give me problems in the future?
There is a different syntax for a  initializer list?

Comment: @nostyn `It could give me problems in the future?` No. But it could give you problems in the past. You can use the pre-C++11 direct initialization if you need to.

Comment: This is not a problem. I would not go off-topic but: If to use the vector I use: "vector<class> obj(size);" || And together with the initializer list: "vector<class> obj;" and then ":obj(size)" || If you wanted to enter ":obj(size)" outside the initializer list, what is the syntax? (For example, to create within a separate function)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your question is: *"how do I initialize all the objects in an array with the exact same constructor call?"*

If that's the case, the easiest way of doing so is using [`std::vector`'s constructor (2)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> ```
>      vector( size_type count, 
>              const T& value,
>              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
> ```
>
> > Constructs the container with `count` copies of elements with value `value`.

Your example then becomes:

```
std::vector<MyClass> obj(5, MyClass{x, y});
```

---

If you really want to use a C-style array, you will have to manually invoke constructors using *placement `new`* and manually invoke destructors if you want to avoid unnecessary *default constructor* calls. Example:

```
std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(MyClass), alignof(MyClass)> obj[5];
for(auto& x : obj) { new(&x) MyClass{x, y}; }

// ... use `obj` ...

for(auto& x : obj) { reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(&x)->~MyClass(); }
```

Note that the above code can be (and should be) refactored into a safe abstraction.

Comment: And wanting to assign two different parameters for each object in the vector?

Comment: @nostyn: you have to spell them out one by one. `std::vector::vector(initialier_list)` allows you to do that easily.

Comment: Okay! Grazie mille :)